# Git "does not appear to be a git repository"

Tags: git

I am trying to install git on a server and have some problem when I try to perform the first push.
I successfully installed git on the server, created the repository locally and on the server but when I try to make the first push I get this message:

```
stdin: is not a tty
fatal: '/my_repo.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I googled it and followed everything I could find but nothing worked. What could be wrong?

Comment: Is the path on the remote server really `/my_repo.git`? Or is it in your home directory or something?

Comment: I wasn't sure so I tried with `my_repo.git`and `/my_repo.git`and nothing works

Comment: On your server, go to the directory that is the repository and type `pwd`. The output is the full path of the repository, make sure you use that.

Comment: Where is the repository installed on your server?  Are you connecting to the remote server using `ssh`?  Have you verified that `ssh` functionality is working outside of `git`?  How did you connect your local repository to the remote repository -- did you use `git clone`?  What command did you type exactly?  Did you use `git remote add`?  Again, what was the exact command?  Can you show us your full `git push` command line (that is, are you typing anything other than simply `git push`)?

Comment: thanks @tpg2114 for the `pwd` command I did not know how to get the full path

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I will assume you are using ssh to clone your repo.

That means you need the full path of the repo on the server in your ssh address:

```
git clone ssh://sshuser@serverIP/full/absolute/path/to/my_repo
```

Note: if your 'my_repo' is a bare one (to allow pushing), that would be:

```
git clone ssh://sshuser@serverIP/full/absolute/path/to/my_repo.git
```

The `stdin: is not a tty` simply means that in the `.bashrc` of the `sshuser` account, there is something expecting an input.

---

[Abpostman1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3747731/abpostman1) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391522/git-does-not-appear-to-be-a-git-repository/10392265?noredirect=1#comment132159062_10392265):

> Had this issue because I was trying to push in a `--bare` repo non empty.
> Even if it was exactly the same files, I had the same error message: "`Not git repository`"
>
> I had to backup my `/httpdocs` remote folder, create an empty new `/httpdocs` folder, do again `git init --bare` and re-push from local.
>
> My remote address : `url = ssh://magento@magento/home/magento/httpdocs` (with a private/public key in both sides)

Comment: Thanks it worked, it was indeed the full path that was missing. The `stdin: is not a tty`error is still here though, I will try to fix it.

Comment: It is also possible to use ~ in the path when you refer to a project in your home directory, e.g. `ssh://name@server/~/myproj/`

Comment: yah, it work's for me too. thank you from saving me from frustating

Comment: Had this issue because I was trying to push in a --bare repo non empty. Even if it was exactly the same files, I had the same error message: "Not git repository"  I had to backup my /httpdocs remote folder, create an empty new **/httpdocs** folder, do again `git init --bare` and re-push from local. My remote address : `url = ssh://magento@magento/home/magento/httpdocs` (with a private/public key in both sides)

Comment: @Abpostman1 Thank you for your feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 11):

May be you forgot to run `git --bare init` on the remote folder 
That was my problem

Answer (score 1):

Or, you can simply use:

```
git clone user@server:/full/path/to/your/directory
```

Answer (score 1):

A non-jailed/non-chrooted git user may also be the issue source, and setting the user's home directory (`~/`) may also help. For example, change:

```sh
git clone -- 'ssh://user@host:port/dir/repo.git';
```

to

```sh
git clone -- 'ssh://user@host:port/~/dir/repo.git';
```

Related: [Git "does not appear to be a git repository"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391522/git-does-not-appear-to-be-a-git-repository#comment50985463_10392265) (*It is also possible to use ~ in the path when you*...)