# Git pull error: "fatal: Couldn't find remote ref master" from Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I upload my application on heroku. But I face some problems. What the problem: fatal: 'priroda' does not appear to be a git repository?

```
~/priroda$ git pull
fatal: 'priroda' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

~/priroda$ git remote -v
    heroku  git@heroku.com:secure-anchorage-3129.git (fetch)
    heroku  git@heroku.com:secure-anchorage-3129.git (push)
    origin  priroda (fetch)
    origin  priroda (push)
```

**When I add this command: git push heroku master I receive many mistakes:**

```
~/priroda$ git remote add origin git@heroku.com:secure-anchorage-3129.git

~/priroda$ git pull origin master
Initializing repository, done.
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref master

~/priroda$ git push heroku master
Initializing repository, done.
Counting objects: 117, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (104/104), done.
Writing objects: 100% (117/117), 126.46 KiB, done.
Total 117 (delta 16), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using 1.6.3
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       Your Gemfile lists the gem pg (>= 0) more than once.
       You should probably keep only one of them.
       While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
       Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Installing multi_json 1.10.1
       Installing rake 10.3.2
       Installing i18n 0.6.9
       Installing builder 3.0.4
       Installing journey 1.0.4
       Installing erubis 2.7.0
       Installing hike 1.2.3
       Installing rack 1.4.5
       Installing tilt 1.4.1
       Installing mime-types 1.25.1
       Installing polyglot 0.3.5
       Installing arel 3.0.3
       Installing acts_as_indexed 0.8.3
       Installing tzinfo 0.3.39
       Installing addressable 2.3.6
       Installing babosa 0.3.11
       Installing coffee-script-source 1.7.0
       Installing execjs 2.2.0
       Installing thor 0.19.1
       Installing orm_adapter 0.5.0
       Installing excon 0.37.0
       Installing bcrypt 3.1.7
       Installing netrc 0.7.7
       Installing json 1.8.1
       Using bundler 1.6.3
       Installing rubyzip 1.1.4
       Installing rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.2
       Installing rails_stdout_logging 0.0.3
       Installing sass 3.3.8
       Installing truncate_html 0.9.2
       Installing will_paginate 3.0.5
       Installing activesupport 3.2.18
       Installing rails-i18n 0.7.4
       Installing rack-cache 1.2
       Installing rack-test 0.6.2
       Installing rack-ssl 1.3.4
       Installing warden 1.2.3
       Installing dragonfly 0.9.15
       Installing sprockets 2.2.2
       Installing rest-client 1.6.7
       Installing treetop 1.4.15
       Installing launchy 2.4.2
       Installing coffee-script 2.2.0
       Installing bcrypt-ruby 3.1.5
       Installing heroku-api 0.3.18
       Installing uglifier 2.5.1
       Installing rdoc 3.12.2
       Installing rails_12factor 0.0.2
       Installing activemodel 3.2.18
       Installing mail 2.5.4
       Installing heroku 3.8.4
       Installing sdoc 0.3.20
       Installing actionpack 3.2.18
       Installing activerecord 3.2.18
       Installing activeresource 3.2.18
       Installing actionmailer 3.2.18
       Installing routing-filter 0.3.1
       Installing railties 3.2.18
       Installing awesome_nested_set 2.1.6
       Installing friendly_id 4.0.10.1
       Installing globalize 3.1.0
       Installing coffee-rails 3.2.2
       Installing refinerycms-i18n 2.1.0
       Installing devise 2.2.8
       Installing decorators 1.0.3
       Installing rails 3.2.18
       Installing jquery-rails 2.3.0
       Installing sass-rails 3.2.6
       Installing seo_meta 1.4.0
       Installing pg 0.17.1
       Installing refinerycms-core 2.1.2
       Installing refinerycms-dashboard 2.1.2
       Installing refinerycms-authentication 2.1.2
       Installing refinerycms-images 2.1.2
       Installing refinerycms-pages 2.1.2
       Installing refinerycms-resources 2.1.2
       Installing refinerycms-acts-as-indexed 1.0.0
       Installing refinerycms 2.1.2
       Your bundle is complete!
       Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
       It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
       Post-install message from bcrypt-ruby:
       #######################################################
       The bcrypt-ruby gem has changed its name to just bcrypt.  Instead of
       installing `bcrypt-ruby`, you should install `bcrypt`.  Please update your
       dependencies accordingly.
       #######################################################
       Post-install message from rdoc:
       Depending on your version of ruby, you may need to install ruby rdoc/ri data:
       <= 1.8.6 : unsupported
       = 1.8.7 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
       = 1.9.1 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
       >= 1.9.2 : nothing to do! Yay!
       Post-install message from heroku:
       !    The `heroku` gem has been deprecated and replaced with the Heroku Toolbelt.
       !    Download and install from: https://toolbelt.heroku.com
       !    For API access, see: https://github.com/heroku/heroku.rb
       Post-install message from friendly_id:
       NOTE: FriendlyId 4.x breaks compatibility with 3.x. If you're upgrading
       from 3.x, please see this document:
       http://rubydoc.info/github/norman/friendly_id/master/file/WhatsNew.md
       Post-install message from globalize:
       Globalize has extracted versioning support to a separate gem named
       globalize-versioning. If you are using versioning (with paper_trail
       or any other versioning gem), please add the line
       "gem 'globalize-versioning'" to your Gemfile and go to the github
       page at globalize/globalize-versioning if you encounter any problems.
       Note that the globalize-versioning gem does not delegate versions to
       the translation table, so you will have to update your syntax to
       the form: `post.translation.versions`. See the globalize-versioning
       readme for details.
       Bundle completed (25.95s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
       rake aborted!
       PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused
       Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
       TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
       /tmp/build_c4c36556-f948-4d00-9345-e2e4903f11f4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1222:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_c4c36556-f948-4d00-9345-e2e4903f11f4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1222:in `new'
       /tmp/build_c4c36556-f948-4d00-9345-e2e4903f11f4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1222:in `connect'
       /tmp/build_c4c36556-f948-4d00-9345-e2e4903f11f4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:324:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_c4c36556-f948-4d00-9345-e2e4903f11f4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `new'
       /tmp/build_c4c36556-f948-4d00-9345-e2e4903f11f4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `postgresql_connection'
       /tmp/build_c4c36556-f948-4d00-9345-e2e4903f11f4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:315:in `new_connection'
       /tmp/build_c4c36556-f948-4d00-9345-e2e4903f11f4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:325:in `checkout_new_connection'
       /tmp/build_c4c36556-f948-4d00-9345-e2e4903f11f4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:247:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
       /tmp/build_c4c36556-f948-4d00-9345-e2e4903f11f4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `loop'
       /tmp/build_c4c36556-f948-4d00-9345-e2e4903f11f4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `block in checkout'
       /tmp/build_c4c36556-f948-4d00-9345-e2e4903f11f4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:239:in `checkout'
       /tmp/build_c4c36556-f948-4d00-9345-e2e4903f11f4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:102:in `block in connection'
       /tmp/build_c4c36556-f948-4d00-9345-e2e4903f11f4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:101:in `connection'
       /tmp/build_c4c36556-f948-4d00-9345-e2e4903f11f4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection'
       /tmp/build_c4c36556-f948-4d00-9345-e2e4903f11f4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:171:in `retrieve_connection'
       /tmp/build_c4c36556-f948-4d00-9345-e2e4903f11f4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:145:in `connection'
       /tmp/build_c4c36556-f948-4d00-9345-e2e4903f11f4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:310:in `clear_cache!'
       /tmp/build_c4c36556-f948-4d00-9345-e2e4903f11f4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:103:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
       /tmp/build_c4c36556-f948-4d00-9345-e2e4903f11f4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:418:in `_run__2404055040551563881__prepare__433825113203608011__callbacks'
       /tmp/build_c4c36556-f948-4d00-9345-e2e4903f11f4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
       /tmp/build_c4c36556-f948-4d00-9345-e2e4903f11f4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
       /tmp/build_c4c36556-f948-4d00-9345-e2e4903f11f4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
       /tmp/build_c4c36556-f948-4d00-9345-e2e4903f11f4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.18/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:74:in `prepare!'
       /tmp/build_c4c36556-f948-4d00-9345-e2e4903f11f4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.18/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:48:in `prepare!'
       /tmp/build_c4c36556-f948-4d00-9345-e2e4903f11f4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:47:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
       /tmp/build_c4c36556-f948-4d00-9345-e2e4903f11f4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
       /tmp/build_c4c36556-f948-4d00-9345-e2e4903f11f4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
       /tmp/build_c4c36556-f948-4d00-9345-e2e4903f11f4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_c4c36556-f948-4d00-9345-e2e4903f11f4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
       /tmp/build_c4c36556-f948-4d00-9345-e2e4903f11f4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_c4c36556-f948-4d00-9345-e2e4903f11f4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
       /tmp/build_c4c36556-f948-4d00-9345-e2e4903f11f4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
       /tmp/build_c4c36556-f948-4d00-9345-e2e4903f11f4/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_c4c36556-f948-4d00-9345-e2e4903f11f4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
       /tmp/build_c4c36556-f948-4d00-9345-e2e4903f11f4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
       /tmp/build_c4c36556-f948-4d00-9345-e2e4903f11f4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_c4c36556-f948-4d00-9345-e2e4903f11f4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
       /tmp/build_c4c36556-f948-4d00-9345-e2e4903f11f4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
       /tmp/build_c4c36556-f948-4d00-9345-e2e4903f11f4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/application.rb:305:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
       /tmp/build_c4c36556-f948-4d00-9345-e2e4903f11f4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.18/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:93:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_c4c36556-f948-4d00-9345-e2e4903f11f4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.18/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_c4c36556-f948-4d00-9345-e2e4903f11f4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.18/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:23:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
       /tmp/build_c4c36556-f948-4d00-9345-e2e4903f11f4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.18/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
       Tasks: TOP => environment
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !     Attempted to access a nonexistent database:
 !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pre-provision-database
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

To git@heroku.com:secure-anchorage-3129.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:secure-anchorage-3129.git'
~/priroda$
```

Comment: if you type git remote -v in terminal what do you get?

Comment: I add to post more information!

Comment: I don't know what tutorial you're following, but this is clearly not working because `origin` isn't set to a remote repository hosted on something like GitHub or Bitbucket. You usually don't want to set `origin` to Heroku itself, since it's not really meant to be used for remote Git repo hosting, such site hosting.

Comment: Related: [fatal: does not appear to be a git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7318918/456814).

Comment: Related: [Git “does not appear to be a git repository”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391522/git-does-not-appear-to-be-a-git-repository).

Comment: Related: [git 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15437719/git-origin-does-not-appear-to-be-a-git-repository).

Comment: View my update, there is a step by step tutorial on how to deploy an app on heroku, also there are plenty of video tutorials on youtube, just look for `deploy rails to heroku`.

Answer (score 11):

You need to add the origin remote:

1. Delete the current one

   `git remote rm origin`
2. Add the git remote link ex: (https://user@bitbucket.org/test.git or https://github.com/user/test.git)

   `git remote add origin link`
3. `git pull origin master` (or other branch)

If you are trying to pull you app from heroku

```
git pull heroku master
```

Or if you try to upload a new version to heroku

```
git push heroku master
```

[EDIT]

Please fallow this [tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/quickstart), when you reach the bottom of the page click on Rails.

Comment: What the link? I am begginer. secure-anchorage-3129.git - this is link or not?

Comment: Where do you host you app, on github or bitbucket? Or just locally?

Comment: Just localy. I will add more information in my post.

Comment: I added my post! I have a new problem!

Comment: Check my updates, normally you use origin remote for a app hosted on github or bitbucket or similar services. But if you have your app uploaded on heroku, only you need to use the heroku remote.

Comment: If my project don't upload on github or bitbucket? But localy. When I git pull heroku master I receive this message:  fatal: Couldn't find remote ref master

Comment: Is your app uploaded on heroku?

Comment: See on the my post! I have giant number of mistakes!

Comment: Is your app uploaded on heroku? - Yes!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56424/discussion-between-uhn-nohn-and-cat).

Comment: @Cat what tutorial are you following? You're not really supposed to pull from Heroku, `origin` should be set to something like a GitHub or a Bitbucket remote repository instead. If you did that, then you wouldn't have this problem.

Answer (score 5):

Check to see if your remote repo is empty or not, if is empty you need add something and push from local repo.

Answer (score 2):

Did you run `git init` and then `git add .` and `git commit -m "Init"` before you added the origin and master?

Answer (score 1):

Though not the same software, I had this issue with SourceTree and BitBucket when I tried to pull right after creating and cloning a new repository. As it had no commits, no branches had automatically been created, so `master` didn't exist yet. Solution - just had to do a commit and push (or create the `master` branch manually).

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the .git directory exists. If it is not the case, use `git clone <URL of the repository>` to get the repository.

If the .git directory exists, you should check if the remote repository has been set using `git remote -v`, as uhn-nohn suggested.

If the remote repository (origin) isn't set, use `git remote add origin <URL of the repository>` to set it.

Comment: I just saw in one of your answer that your repository is local (no remote repository). git pull doesn't have any sense for a repository that isn't linked to a remote repository since this command tries to pull modifications from a remote repository.

Answer (score -2):

It means that your local directory (`~/priroda`) goes not contain a git repository.