# git pull-remote branch cannot find remote ref [ Tried many solution yet failed ]

Tags: svn, bitbucket

When I do git branch -a, this is what I see:

```
master   remotes/svn/CI-Migration   remotes/svn/migrationservice_codebase_chef   remotes/svn/tags/fulfillment-bnw-migration-A22-Version-1.0   remotes/svn/tags/fulfillment-bnw-migration-A22-Version-2.0   remotes/svn/tags/fulfillment-bnw-migration-A23-Version-3.0   remotes/svn/tags/migration-release-0.4   remotes/svn/tags/migration-release-0.5   remotes/svn/tags/migration-release-0.6   remotes/svn/tags/migration-release-0.6@40322   remotes/svn/tags/migration-release-0.7   remotes/svn/tags/migration-release-0.8   remotes/svn/tags/migration-service-dec-3   remotes/svn/trunk
```

I tried doing following to push (NOTE : mentioned error corresponding to those commands) :

1) git pull --rebase(There is no tracking information for the current branch..)

2) git pull  master (fatal: Couldn't find remote ref Master)

3) git pull(There is no tracking information for the current branch..)

4) git pull origin master (fatal: Couldn't find remote ref Master)

Nothing works at all( returns with one or other error)

Can someone help me with git push here.

Comment: What's the output of `git remote -v` ?

Comment: What's the output of `git remote -v` ?

Comment: origin <HOST-URL> (fetch)
origin <HOST-URL> (push)

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24452083/7338544