# Git repository - how do I clone /home/user/.git

Tags: git, git-clone

I've got a website on a VPS and I'd like to create an offline clone using Git.

So what I did on my VPS:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "comment"
```

Which created a .git folder. I am not sure now how I am supposed to continue in order to clone the git repository to my local machine.

I've tried using: `git clone ssh://user@IP/home/user/.git` but I get the following messages:

```
fatal: '/home/user/.git' does not appear to be a git repository 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Can you please let me know what I am missing here?

Comment: To clone the repo you need to indicate the path to the project and not the path to the `.git` folder

Comment: @JoëlSalamin So instead of /home/user/.git just /home/user/ ? Because that didn't work either. Unless you mean something else..

Comment: what is the error thrown now?

Comment: all you need is one command, `git clone ssh://username@site.com:port/remote/dir/public_html /home/user/local/dir`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git "does not appear to be a git repository"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391522/git-does-not-appear-to-be-a-git-repository)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should just "ignore" the existence of the .git directory:

```
git clone ssh://user@IP:/home/user/
```

should do the trick (if `ssh user@IP` works of course).

**NOTE:**
not sure it's a good idea to make your whole "user" directory a git repository. using a subdirectory is probably a good idea.

**EDIT:** 
in this case file permissions were also an issue in copying files from a linux pc to a windows pc...

Comment: Hello Chris, doing this I still get the same error `fatal: '/home/user/' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.` I've also got .gitignore to ignore everything but public_html which I want to copy

Comment: in which directory did you do the `git init` command? I suppose in `/home/user/` ?

Comment: Yes, I did it on /home/user/ and the .git folder is under there. I've also checked ssh which works.

Comment: then I suggest you to try it out locally first: create a temporary dir; make it a git repository; and clone it to another directory; check if that works...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76978/discussion-between-chris-maes-and-user3096206).