# Allow access to personnal git server (gogs) on dockerized ubuntu

Tags: git, ubuntu, gogs

I just set up an ubuntu server in a docker, and installed [gogs](https://gogs.io/) on it.

Everything seemed to work fine: **I can access gogs via firefox without any problem**, create repos or add files, but when I try to `git clone` a repo from it, or `git push` from my local computer, I get an timeout error:

`fatal: unable to access 'http://xx.x.xxx.xx:8001/username/test.git/': Recv failure: Connection was reset`

Some informations:

- As you can see, I do not have a proper dns, I access it via the raw ip and port.
- Iptables is configured to allow input/output tcp on the port 8001
- gogs run as an init.d service
- The gogs service's user has rw access to the gogs_repository directory

Conf: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, Gogs 0.11.66

**UPDATE**:

1. I configured apache2 as a proxy to be able to access gogs via the server's name and without specifying the port (by redirecting requests to the port 8001). Problem is still there.
2. **I managed to clone a repo** via SSH by using the full path to the repo: `git clone ssh://user@myserver/home/user/gogs-repositories/gogs-user/test.git`, thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391522/git-does-not-appear-to-be-a-git-repository)

But the problem is still there when I try to clone using http. Any idea?

**UPDATE2**:
Here is the detailed trace of the git command that I run from my local computer:

```
$ git clone http://xx.x.xxx.xx:8001/user/test
14:50:09.131427 exec-cmd.c:236          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/mingw32/bin
14:50:09.132424 git.c:415               trace: built-in: git clone http://10.5.255.28:8001/user/test
Cloning into 'test'...
14:50:09.179300 run-command.c:637       trace: run_command: git remote-http origin http://10.5.255.28:8001/user/test
14:50:09.224179 exec-cmd.c:236          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/mingw32/libexec/git-core
14:50:09.228170 git.c:671               trace: exec: git-remote-http origin http://10.5.255.28:8001/user/test
14:50:09.228170 run-command.c:637       trace: run_command: git-remote-http origin http://10.5.255.28:8001/user/test
14:50:09.280032 exec-cmd.c:236          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/mingw32/libexec/git-core
* Couldn't find host 10.5.255.28 in the _netrc file; using defaults
*   Trying 10.5.255.28...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 10.5.255.28 (10.5.255.28) port 8001 (#0)
> GET /user/test/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.5.255.28:8001
User-Agent: git/2.19.1.windows.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
Pragma: no-cache

* Recv failure: Connection was reset
* Closing connection 0
fatal: unable to access 'http://xx.x.xxx.xx:8001/user/test/': Recv failure: Connection was reset
```