# Jenkins can't find local git repository

Tags: windows, git, jenkins, local

I am currently installaing a pipeline for my Visual Studio projects with Jenkins (on Windows).

I installed the Git Bash and Jenkins successfully, but when I generate a new Jenkins project I need to give a Repository URL. I entered the path to my project and got the following message:

> Failed to connect to repository : Error performing command: git.exe
>   ls-remote -h file:///Users/myusername/Documents/Visual Studio
>   2015/Projects/QtTestApplication HEAD

I already searched for a solution and changed the user from Jenkins to the admin:

[Jenkins configuration of git plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15257652/jenkins-configuration-of-git-plugin)

I double-checked the userchange in the Jenkins systeminformations (it's really running on the admin).

However i still get the same error as before and I'm not quite sure what to enter in this form.
I already tried "escaping" the whitespaces like this:

> Failed to connect to repository : Error performing command: git.exe
>   ls-remote -h file:///Users/myusername/Documents/Visual\ Studio\
>   2015/Projects/QtTestApplication HEAD

EDIT: Solution Part 1

I found out, that git was not found by Jenkins and that i had to add it manually to it (edit the PATH variable).

Comment: For whatever user Jenkins is running under, have you tried opening a shell and trying that exact command? That is, `git ls-remote <your git url>`. Also maybe, there's a typo in your git url? Like if it's a network path, there should be four slashes after file:. So, file:////Users instead of file:///Users

Comment: I tried your extra slashes and the result was the same, but thanks for your reply :)

Comment: Is it a local path?

Comment: yes, the jenkins is running on the same machine (localhost). I tried your command, too, but apprently the windows git-bash can't handle the file protocol

Comment: Jenkins can actually take normal windows paths like "C:\Users\foo\bar" which are working for me now, so the problem is solved! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Oh, great. I was going to suggest something like file:///c/path/to/remote.git (three slashes with the drive letter). That's how I have my local repo setup and the remote is sitting right next to it.

Comment: Also, this may be useful in the future: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols