# git plugin on windows command fails from Jenkins, succeeds in shell

Tags: windows, git, jenkins

I'm setting up Jenkins on my windows build machine, with the [Git Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin#GitPlugin-). I'm using a directory on a network drive Z: as the git repository for now. I enter "z:\my\repo\path" for the Repository URL, and I get:

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "git.exe -c core.askpass=true ls-remote -h z:\my\repo\path HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: fatal: 'z:\my\repo\path' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Yet if I open a fresh command prompt and type that command, it works without error (and also no output):

```
> git.exe -c core.askpass=true ls-remote -h z:\my\repo\path HEAD
>
```

What may possibly be the issue? I am not even sure where to begin. I've set the `PATH` and `GIT_HOME` system environment variables and restarted Jenkins, so clearly it is finding the executable.

I've tried the `file:///`-style path and had the same results.

---

Output of the manual command with `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1` and `GIT_TRACE=1` set:

```
15:43:24.905801 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'ls-remote' '-h' 'z:\\my\\repo\\path' 'HEAD'
15:43:24.905801 run-command.c:343       trace: run_command: 'git-upload-pack '\''z:\\my\\repo\\path'\'''
```

Comment: Which user does Jenkins run as?

Comment: Could you please post the output of the manual command with the following vars set: `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE=1 git.exe -c ...`

Comment: @AshutoshJindal: Certainly, see the update. It runs as the "Local System account". Changing it to use the same user as when I manually enter the command didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Have you changed anything else than "Repository URL" in your scm settings?

Comment: @SevenEleven: Nope, just installed the plugin, selected "Git" from the project settings, and entered the folder path

Comment: Ahhhh intriguing - I failed to mention that `z:\` is a network drive, and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410793/unable-to-get-jenkins-and-git-to-play-nice) indicates that I have to specify the full path... trying to get this to work now

Comment: Yes, that was it. `//network-host-name/path/to/repo` worked.

Comment: ah sorry, I should have been more explicit, that's what I meant by the 'UNC' path. Updating with link now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem could be around correctly setting up the SSH keys.

#### First suggestion - [UNC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg465305.aspx) path for the repo

Can you try using the `file:////` format for the repo instead of windows path?

If it's a share try using `git clone file:////<host>/<share>/<path>` instead.

Please use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519933/git-clone-repo-across-local-file-system-in-windows) as reference.

#### Second suggestion - SSH Keys

From https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin#GitPlugin- :
(though the error is different that what you have)

> Some windows fun
>
> If you did everything, you should now have a ~/.ssh folder
>   (c:\Users\Bob.ssh for instance) and this folder contains your keys.
>   At that point, you may even be able to manually (from the console),
>   clone your repository but Jenkins keeps failing with something like
>   this:
>
> code 128: Cloning into C:\Program Files\Jenkins\jobs\PG3\workspace...
>   fatal: 
>   The remote end hung up unexpectedly
>
> **If you run into this issue, you may need to copy the id_rsa* files
>   from your ~./.ssh to another folder. Find your git.exe and check if
>   there is an .ssh folder there. If so, copy ~./ssh/id_rsa* to this
>   folder and try again.**

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions - I had already tried `file:///` and it didn't work. For the latter, I don't have any `id_rsa*` files, but I tried creating the `.ssh` folder where `git.exe` is and still no luck...

Comment: Interestingly `file:///<host>/<share>...` didn't work, only `//<host>/<share>...`

Comment: Is that with four slashes? i.e. `file:////` instead of `file:///` ?

Comment: Ah yes, four worked as well... interesting!